# Не получается запустить установленный модуль chalk в node.js

Tags: node.js

Описание проблемы в скринах. Не могу понять, в чем дело.

[image: Модуль установлен]

[image: Вызываю модуль]

[image: Ошибка - не поддерживается модуль]

Comment: Описание проблемы должно быть текстом, а не «на скринах». Покажите полный package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IMPORTANT](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v5.0.0): Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or a build tool, you will probably want to **use Chalk 4 for now**.

This package is now pure ESM. Please [read this](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c).

- If you use TypeScript, you will want to stay on Chalk 4 until TypeScript 4.6 is out. [Why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46452).
- If you use a bundler, make sure it supports ESM and that you have correctly configured it for ESM.
- The Chalk issue tracker is not a support channel for your favorite build/bundler tool.

Comment: Или переходи на `picocolors`, он таким «фашизмом» не страдает :-)

Comment: @AlexeyTen sindresorhus пересаживает комьюнити на ESM :)

Answer (score 0):

Скринов для понимания вопроса вполне достаточно. Судя по коду в index.js, проблема возникла при ускоренном изучении node.js (возможно у Владилена Минина). У него инсталлируется модуль chalk v2.4.2.
Сейчас командой `npm i chalk` подключается модуль v5.0.0, в котором require не работает. Самое простое решение:

1. Сносите подключенный модуль `npm uninstall chalk`.
2. Подключаете модуль предыдущей версии `npm install chalk@4.1.2`
   После этого написанный вами код прекрасно отработает. Красное слово testing будет вам наградой.